# Similarity between time series

Tags: time-series, association-measure, canonical-correlation

Consider two sets A and B of time series, with dimensions (Txn) and (Txk) respectively and k

Each time series in A is associated to one or more series in B. The association is based on some prior expectation that the series are "similar".

I apologise as the question is vague at this stage. Any ideas on how to verify statistically the described association?

Comment: Canonical correlations?

Comment: [Here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/abc6/56f8413eaddb7373c64913d1e829944afea4.pdf) is a relevant paper